# AngularFirstore is not defined

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I am doing a simply angular app with angularfire and firebase. But I have a problem with Angularfire. The error on console says:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: AngularFirstore is not defined

    at eval (app.module.ts:15)
    at eval (app.module.ts:18)
```

my *app.modudule.ts* is

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { AngularFireModule } from "angularfire2";
import { environment } from "../environments/environment";
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [AngularFirstore],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Its AngulaFirstore spelling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `AngularFirestore` instead of `AngularFirstore`.

Comment: Oh god ...  these spelling. Thank you a lot. I will accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

Spelling mistake. Its AngularFirestore